# How can I read a specific string from the Serial Port?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm talking serially to a Smart Motor and I'm trying to look for the specific string "@ Positon" coming back from the motor.  When I see that I want to set the Play button to be enabled (btnPlay.Enabled=true;).

I've tried every way but can't seem to fit it to the following code. What can I place in my code below where I can test the incoming data and then trigger the enable?

The following code works - I just don't know where and how to read for specific information.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // If the com port has been closed, do nothing
  if (!comport.IsOpen) return;

  // Determain which mode (string or binary) the user is in
  if (CurrentDataMode == DataMode.Text)
  {
    // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
    string data = comport.ReadExisting();

    // Display the text to the user in the terminal
    Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, data);
  }
  else
  {
    // Obtain the number of bytes waiting in the port's buffer
    int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;

    // Create a byte array buffer to hold the incoming data
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

    // Read the data from the port and store it in our buffer
    comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

    // Show the user the incoming data in hex format
    Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, ByteArrayToHexString(buffer));
  }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate your question a bir further, please. Are you receiving any incoming data at all? Or is your question about how to include the text check?

Comment: This code cannot work, you normally only get one or two bytes (or characters).  You must collect the entire response from the motor controller, you need a buffer to store the intermediate bytes you get.  And you must detect the end of the response, most controllers will send a special byte to indicate it, like a line-feed.

Comment: I send a sting value commanding the motor to a step position.. for example, I'll send "2400G" <cr> which the motor then sends a response back like "2400G Received". The the motor will send back "Going to 2400", then when it reaches position 2400, the motor then sends "@ position". What I need to do is prevent any other actions until is reads the "@ position" string